# Popup UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, popup

I'm trying to make a popup which will be presented by pressing a button. Tried to follow instructions which i found in google but my pop view presenting in a full screen and its background is black. 
Here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

    @IBAction func someButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let popupVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("hello") as! popupViewController
        popupVC.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
        popupVC.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(300, 300)
        let pVC = popupVC.popoverPresentationController
        pVC?.permittedArrowDirections = .Any
        pVC?.delegate = self
        pVC?.sourceView = sender
        pVC?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 1, height: 1)
        presentViewController(popupVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

What I'am doing wrong?

Comment: You can use this pod: EzPopup (https://github.com/huynguyencong/EzPopup)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

To make your view controller shown as a popup, you should set the following:

```
popupVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
popupVC.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
```

You should also design your view controller's position, size to make it look like a popup.

Here is my popup that i did before.

[image]

Comment: Is this possible programmatically. Please explain

Comment: @n-der: What thing do you want to do programmatically? Please explain.

Comment: I wanted to present a UICollectionViewController as a popup programmatically. Thanks.

Comment: @N.Der, yeah, whatever is part (or subclass) of the `UIViewController` can be.

Comment: Don't forget to set backgroundView color with alpha less than 1. else you won't get the required results. Above answer needed to be updated to add transparent background color.

Comment: In my case i added these two lines. 
view.backgroundColor = UIColor(0.0/255.0, 0.0/255.0, 0.0/255.0, alpha:0.3)
view.subviews.first?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear (This line is compulsory if PopupVC is ViewController not View)

Answer (score 12):

At the parent controller:

```
let vc = ViewController()
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
vc.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

At the pop up controller, use this to enable showing the parent controller in the background:

```
self.definesPresentationContext = true
```

Don't forget to set a **translucent background** to your pop up controller.

-- Reference from: [Presenting a popup view controller programmatically - Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/7n2rgj/presenting_a_popup_view_controller_programatically/) --

Answer (score 0):

Another simple solution, using EzPopup (https://github.com/huynguyencong/EzPopup). It's very simple with just a few lines of code:

```
// init YourViewController
let contentVC = ...

// Init popup view controller with content is your content view controller
let popupVC = PopupViewController(contentController: contentVC, popupWidth: 100, popupHeight: 200)

// show it by call present(_ , animated:) method from a current UIViewController
present(popupVC, animated: true)
```

Comment: 2018-09-04 21:22:03.062970+0300 Project[58459:1907794] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modal view controller on itself. Presenting controller is <Project.PopupViewController: 0x7fd20b66c940>.'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: @MihailSalari You should call present(...) method from another view controller.

Comment: That's a bad practice.

Comment: Why it's a bad practice? It is like present other view controller.