# Custom Alert in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uialertcontroller

i have been searching for a long time to make custom Alert Views myself. But there was no success. What i do is i design a view in the xib file in the story board and load it in the application but it just shows up like regular views. What i want to do is present this view as AlertController in iOS >= 8 using Swift 3. What i did is

```swift
let alert = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("xib file to load", owner: self, options: nil)?.last as! UIView

// showAlert(alert: alert)
func showAlert(alert: UIView){
    let windows = UIApplication.shared.windows
    let lastWindow = windows.last
    print(lastWindow)
    alert.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 300)
    alert.center = self.view.center
    lastWindow?.addSubview(alert)
}

func removeAlert(alert: UIView){
    alert.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

This just shows and hides the view. But i want it to present like UIAlertController. I want everything in the background dim a and only focus on this view. How can i achieve that. Please help me through this.

Comment: https://github.com/SalmanGhumsani/SGSImpleAlert 

may be it will help you

Comment: this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37205789/popup-uiviewcontroller

Comment: try this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600779/how-can-i-customize-an-ios-alert-view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you should **never** touch `window` on iOS. Except for extremely rare special cases.

You can create in your .xib a view with transparent or semi-transparent background. Then you can define a protocol to present this view:

```
protocol AlertPresenting {}

extension AlertPresenting {
    func showAlert(_ onView: UIView) {
        if let alert = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("AlertView", owner: nil, options: nil)![0] as? AlertView {
            alert.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            onView.addSubview(alert)
            //here define constraints
            onView.bringSubviewToFront(alert)
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use it on any `viewController`:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, AlertPresenting {
    func someFunction() {
        showAlert(onView: self.view)
    }
}
```

The alert will be above all the `views`.

Comment: will this alert be like alertController? Means everything in the background will be dimmed and the alert will look like its raised a little?

Comment: @SalmanAli you should create the semi-transparent background yourself, as I wrote in the answer. You custom `alertView` should cover the entire screen, but non-transparent view (the alert you want to show) should be smaller.

Answer (score 0):

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Record Inserted", message: 
"Record Inserted", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", 
style:UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))

self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a view controller in storyboard with transparent background view and then present it

```
let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Alert", bundle: .main)
let viewController : UIViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AlertController")

customAlertController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext
customAlertController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.crossDissolve

self.present(customAlertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```